# How to calculate a coefficient of correlation, by year, in R and put results in a dataframe?

Tags: r, pearson-correlation

I want to calculate the coefficient of correlation, by year, in R and put the results in a dataframe (then repeat the process by calculating the coefficient of determination). The following code returns a value which, I'm guessing, is for all years combined. The value appears in the console but not the dataframe.

```
xmasCount_Amt_Coef_Correlation <- xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate %>% 
  group_by(Year.x, YTD_Range.x)

cor(xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate$n, xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate$Amount)
```

A sample screenshot of my source table xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate is shown below. The complete table (dataframe) contains data for 2020-2022. The desired output table looks identical to the source table which is not what I want. I'm obviously missing a step or two but am clueless as to what. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[Source table xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jEc3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you modify as needed, the below code in your project and let me know what you get:

```
library(dplyr)

# Group by year, then calculate corr coeff for each group
xmasCount_Amt_Coef_Correlation <- xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate %>%
  group_by(Year.x) %>%
  summarise(correlation = cor(n, Amount))

# and the result:
xmasCount_Amt_Coef_Correlation
```

One way you could do is (the coefficient of determination is denoted by R^2):

```
# add a new column with the coefficient of determination
xmasCount_Amt_Coef_Correlation <- xmasCount_Amt_Coef_Correlation %>%
  mutate(determination = correlation^2)

# View the resulting data frame
xmasCount_Amt_Coef_Correlation
```

Comment: Thank you, Manoj! I was able to add YTD_Range.x to the group_by and it worked perfectly. Can you please tell me how to modify summarise(correlation = cor(n, Amount)) to calculate the coefficient of determination (r squared)?

Comment: Regarding my above question about calculating the coefficient of determination, I was able to use the following syntax: summarise(rsquared = cor(n, Amount)^2). This obviously requires calculating the coefficient of correlation first but given how easy it is to do this I'm happy with this approach.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply, I have added the requirement in my answer.. please check and let me know if that helps...

Comment: Your suggestion to use mutate(determination = correlation^2) worked perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @BryanSchmidt if you think my answer was exactly what you needed, you could help me by accepting it and upvoting it :) at times these things matter, my friend... enjoy R.

Comment: Done, or at least I hope so. I marked your response as "accepted" but cannot find a way to upvote it. Please advise how I can do more in this regard.

Comment: I guess you do not have enough reputations to do so... :) you must gain at least 15 points.. nevermind... I am happy at least my answer helped you... please remain active here and keep learning R... all the best...